# Any reason not to call KafkaConsumer.poll() with Long.MAX_VALUE?

Tags: apache-kafka

For my app that consume Kafka messages, is there any reason not to call `KafkaConsumer.poll(millisecs)` with `Long.MAX_VALUE` for `millsecs`?

I see many code pass in something like 1000milli, but wouldn't `Long.MAX_VALUE` be ideal, in that, just wait there and be trigged when there's a message appears in the topic.

What's the point of having `poll()` be called with 1sec since if you can pass in `Long.MAX_VALUE`?

Just to clearly illustrate the code:

```
public class MyConsumer implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, LogLine> records = consumer.poll(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            // does something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can call `poll()` with `Long.MAX_VALUE` in every queue, unless you want do something special if queue does not have data in appropriate time.

For example suppose you have two topics A and B in Kafka and topic A has higher priority. In your code you want poll on A, and if A has not record, poll and (possibly) retrieve data from B. In this case you must pass a reasonable timeout to `poll()`

```
while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, LogLine> recordsA = consumerA.poll(1000);
        if (!records.isEmpty()) {
            // does something with recordsA
            continue;
        }
        else {
            ConsumerRecords<String, LogLine> recordsB = consumerB.poll(1000);
            // does something with recordsB
        }
}
```